# Symfony 2.3 production mode urls not resolving

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have just gone through the Symblog tutorials on http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/customising-the-view-more-with-twig.html

In prod mode, if i access the url like so:

> http://local.mysite.co.uk

I get the home page with links to all the blog posts.

However if i click one of the blog posts then I get a 404, in fact any of the links (to the about or contact) all return a 404, eg:

> http://local.mysite.co.uk/12/a-day-with-symfony2

If I then access the prod mode via the app_dev.php all the links work again, ie:

> http://local.mysite.co.uk/app.php/12/a-day-with-symfony2

I have run to ensure the mod rewrites should be working and restarted apache but no joy.

```
sudo a2enmod actions
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks,
John

PS: This is the current vhost file for the dev site i am learning with (Ubuntu lts, apache 2.4, php 5.4ish)

```
<virtualhost *:80>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
  ServerName  mysite.co.uk
  ServerAlias www.mysite.co.uk
  ServerAlias local.mysite.co.uk

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex app.php
  DocumentRoot /var/webroot/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/Symfony/web/

  # Custom log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/webroot/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/webroot/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/log/access.log combined

</virtualhost>
```

When I add an `AllowOverride All` to the vhost file and restart apache I get the follwoing error:

```
 * Starting web server apache2
 * 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 15 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.co.uk.conf:
AllowOverride not allowed here
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: Did you run `a2enmod rewrite`? Is rewriting enabled in your VirtualHost config?

Comment: did you also restart apache after enabling rewrite?

Comment: That returns: Module rewrite already enabled. rewriting is not specifically set in my vhost file for this dev site. I thought this was a globally controlled variable?

Comment: Rewrite is enabled globally, but allowing its use can be done separately for each VirtualHost. Add the following to yours to see if it is the thing missing: `AllowOverride all`.

Comment: Adding AllowOverride All  returns an error when restarting apache (added error to original post)

Comment: You added it between the virtualhost tags, right?

Comment: found the answer, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Altering the vhost worked  (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/308825/maerlyn).

Placing a directory tag with the Allowoverride All fixed the issue. Seems that the rewrites are specific to each vhost.

Here is my config for the symfony tutorial which is now functioning in prod mode:

```
<directory /var/webroot/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/Symfony/web/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</directory>

<virtualhost *:80>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
  ServerName  mysite.co.uk
  ServerAlias www.mysite.co.uk
  ServerAlias local.mysite.co.uk

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex app.php
  DocumentRoot /var/webroot/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/Symfony/web/

  # Custom log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/webroot/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/webroot/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/log/access.log combined

</virtualhost>
```